# Multiple External Configuration Sprintg boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I am using Springboot and developing web services based on those. In my services, I am keeping the configuration at git instead of with project, so that I will be able to change the properties at run-time without restarting the application.

I am using a ConfigServer to fetch the configuartion and all my services are Config Client.

But the issue is my config files are fetched from git based on 
-.properties file, so for ex. if my application name is demo and active profile is testing, then the config file which is getting fetched from git is demo-testing.properties.

But the issue I want to have more than one config file. So how should I mention second config file?
Also the second config file is common to other services also?

So actually I want to use same config file for many services which is located at git?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? Have you looked at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html?

Comment: I have 3 Service A, B, C. I want all of them to use a common config file which is kept at git. Apart from this, all services have there respective config file like A-testing.prop, B-testing.prop etc. How should I do that>